# How to create a template in magento framework?

Tags: templates, frameworks, magento

I want to create a template in magento. How do I do  this. Is there any tutorials for that or book please mention here

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111984/beginning-magento-development/1113562#1113562

Answer (score 2):

The Magento website is a great resource.  Here is a great place to start:  www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/working-with-magento-themes